# Express Route is not working which is defined inside a response callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webstorm, es6-promise

I am defining a route inside in callback response function. But express js gives 404 not found error when i access this route and also if i defined this route outside the function than it works. i have old projects working properly with this logic but new projects are not working.

**IDE: Webstorm 2020.1.1**

Following is my code

**www.js  (Starting Script)**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

let app = require('../src/app');
let debug = require('debug')('whatsapp-bsp:server');
let http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

let port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

let server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  let port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  let bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  let addr = server.address();
  let bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

**app.js**

```
let app = express();
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let logger = require('morgan');
const config = require('../config');

const port = config.PORT;
const PubSub = require('./pubsub');
const amqp = require('./amqp');


app.use("*", function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.method + " " + req.originalUrl);
  next();
});


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('cors')(config.cors));

const indexRouter = require('./routes');
const myRouter = require('./routes/myRouter')

amqp.createChannel().then(async channel => {
  const pubsub = new PubSub(channel);
  app.use('/webhook', myRouter(pubsub)); // This Route Does not work
});
app.use('/', indexRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

console.log("I'm listening on " + port);

module.exports = app;
```

**myRouter.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

module.exports = (pubsub) => {

  router.post('/:value', function (req, res) {
    if (!req.body) {
      res.json({ data: { success: false, error: 'Request Body Required!' } })
    }
    pubsub.publish({ ...req.body, extension: req.params.value }, req.params.value)
      .catch(e => {
        console.log('Error Publishing Messaging!!', e);
        res.json({ data: { success: false, error: 'Error publishing!' } })
      })
    res.json({ data: { success: true, message: 'Published Successfully!' } })
  });
  return router;
}
```

Comment: What exact URL are you trying to use to hit the pubsub route?  Is it `/webhook/someValue`?

Comment: i am trying it from localhost:3000/webhook/someValue but i dont think pubsub affects it, because even i put route inside a simple function and call it the route does not work

Comment: Route only works if  i put route simple in in app.js file like indexRouter